# Selenium - XPath element not found

Tags: selenium

I found the following XPath expression using [FirePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992056/why-doesnt-firepath-work-anymore-since-firefox-51-0-1) and [Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29):

```
//div[@class='itudeBox floatDiv']/div[1]/div/text()[2]
```

This returns the correct value in Selenium.

But when I try the same in [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) → *TestNG*:

```java
selenium.getAttribute("xpath=//div[@class='itudeBox floatDiv']/div[1]/div/text()[2]");
```

It shows an error "Element not found".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Its a huge HTML file. With lot of characters. If I paste it here it will look confusing to you. May be can I post it to your mail ID? If yes can you please provide me your ID?

Comment: Ok now I tried this : selenium.getText("xpath=//div[@class='itudeBox floatDiv']/div[1]/div/text()[2]"); And it says "ERROR: This element has no value; is it really a form field?" Any info on this issue?

Comment: dont provide whole HTMl..just provideHTML related to element which you are trying to identify

Comment: Here you go : Am trying to find the text "AD- Advice"              Am pasting it in 6 comments here because of the character limit to add a comment. Please combine them. Thanks

Comment: <div id="page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:deviation_panel" class="itudeBox floatDiv" style="width: 245px; height: 160px; margin-right: 0px; border-right: 0px;">
<a id="page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:deviation_panel_new_deviation" class="itudeStandardButtonMedium" href="#" name="page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:deviation_panel_new_deviation" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('page_form',event,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data)

Comment: {Richfaces.componentControl.performOperation(event,'oncomplete','#page_form\\:deviation_modalpanel','show')},'similarityGroupingId':'page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:deviation_panel_new_deviation','parameters':

Comment: {'page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:deviation_panel_new_deviation':'page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:deviation_panel_new_deviation','ajaxSingle':'page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:deviation_panel_new_deviation'} ,'containerId':'page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region'} );return false;" style="float: none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">Add a deviation</a>

Comment: <div id="page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:j_id1627" class="itudeBoxList" style="width: 245px; height: 131px;">
<div id="page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:j_id1629:0:j_id1630" class="itudeDeviation itudeDeviationToBeApproved" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('page_form',event,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data)

Comment: {Richfaces.componentControl.performOperation(event,'oncomplete','#page_form\\:deviation_modalpanel','show')},'similarityGroupingId':'page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:j_id1629:0:j_id1646','parameters':{'page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:j_id1629:0:j_id1646':'page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:j_id1629:0:j_id1646'}

Comment: ,'containerId':'page_form:j_id1076:monitor_form:monitor_board_list_table:0:table_details_region:j_id1628'} )">
3/8/12 3:05 PM - Costs - interfaceflor - €&nbsp;5.00
<br>
AD - Advice
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Can u please edit that into your post?

Comment: I am getting element not found exception on these two elements :  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

Answer (score 1):

Try out the below one to locate the element:

```
//div[text()='AD- Advice']
css=div:contains(“AD- Advice”)
//div[contains(text(),'AD- Advice')]
```

Comment: I tried like you said. But all there are failing                   //invalid xpath
//selenium.getAttribute("xpath=//div[text()='AD- Advice']");
//element not found
//selenium.getAttribute("css=div:contains(“AD- Advice”)");
selenium.getAttribute("xpath=//div[contains(text(),'AD- Advice')]");

Comment: selenium.getAttribute("//div[text()='AD- Advice']")

Comment: I got it working. selenium.getText("//div[@class='itudeBox floatDiv']/div[1]/div/text()[2]"); Thank you so much for your time

Comment: A single XPath expressions? Three separate XPath expressions? What is the intent?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
selenium.getText("xpath=//div[@class='itudeBox floatDiv']/div[1]/div");
```

Or:

```
selenium.getText("xpath=//div[@class='itudeBox floatDiv']/div[1]/div[2]");
```

The `getText()` method works on the element and I believe your XPath expression returns the text within an element.