# Why doesn't FirePath work anymore since Firefox 51.0.1?

Tags: firefox, firebug, firepath

I have Firefox version 51.0.1 and Firebug version 2.0.18 (though it just says "deactivated"). I have been installing the latest FirePath over and over, but I don't see it appearing when I click the Firebug icon.

They both are enabled in my extensions. I saw it a few days ago, but I had to reinstall Firefox yesterday for some reason, and both Firebug and FirePath were gone, and it is now giving me problems. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Firebug toolbar button is always shown deactivated since Firefox 51.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929647/firebug-toolbar-button-is-always-shown-deactivated-since-firefox-51-0-1)*

Answer (score 1):

Firebug development is discontinued and it does not work anymore once multi-process Firefox is enabled and clicking the Firebug button opens the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead. You can read more about this in the [related Mozilla Hacks blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).

This also affects FirePath, because it doesn't work with the Firefox DevTools.

They don't have an exact equivalent to it, but allow you to test XPaths via the [`$x()` command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#$x) within the command line. Furthermore, there are requests for [copying the XPath of an element](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=987877) and for [searching for XPaths within the Inspector](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=963933).

There's also a way to get Firebug and FirePath work again by [disabling multi-process Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40910225/432681). Though that is only a temporary solution, because multiple processes will be enforced in an upcoming version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted my Firebug and FirePath, downloaded Firebug version 2.0.18, and installed FirePath again.

It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Firefox has used DevTool instead of Firebug.

You can reactivate Firebug to rework as the above mentioned links.

In `about:config` set the preferences `browser.tabs.remote.autostart`, `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1`, and `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2` to `false`.

Answer (score -1):

I am just sharing what I found while on Google. Instead of downgrading anything, you can use ChroPath. It is available for both - Chrome as well as Firefox.

Chrome plugin: *[ChroPath](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo?hl=en)*

Firefox plugin: *[ChroPath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chropath-for-firefox/)*

Here is the video: *[ChroPath for Firefox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZnMieaLY8c&feature=youtu.be)*

Actual site: *[SelectorsHub](https://medium.com/@mailcoolsanjay/chropath-firepath-for-chrome-browser-3130e72b4754)*