# Search for element by XPath in Firefox 57 DevTools Inspector

Tags: firefox, xpath, scrapy, selector

In Google Chrome, when we inspect the page, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> we have option to find through string: XPath or CSS selector.

In Firefox 57.0.4, but I can select elements using a CSS selector, but not XPath.

Is this disabled in latest Firefox? If not, then how can I use it?

**Note: It is now possible to use xpath in firefox.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox built-in DevTools do not support searching for elements by XPath as of version 70. This request is tracked in [bug 963933](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=963933).

As a workaround you can use the [`$x()` command in the Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands).

Related: [Why doesn't FirePath work anymore since Firefox 51.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992056/why-doesnt-firepath-work-anymore-since-firefox-51-0-1)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but now  [bug 963933](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=963933) is resolved and it's possible to have the same experience as in Chrome by pasting xpath query and getting the result.